# lookup on mongodb 'as' is the same level as the first collection

Tags: mongodb

I tried in several ways but couldn't find it so I can get the expected result, please help me, thank you

```
// table 1
let collection1 = {
 nim: 1234,
 docName: 'one'
}

// table 2
let collection2 = {
 nim: 1234,
 docName: 'two'
}

// query
// this.db ??
// expected results
let result = [
  {docName: 'one'},
  {docName: 'two'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$unionWith`

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      nim: 1234
    }
  },
  {
    $unionWith: {
      coll: "collection2",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            nim: 1234
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      nim: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L1vlNW3Ro-k)

---

Tf collection1 do not have 1234, then the result is empty.

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      nim: 1234
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      from: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unionWith: {
      coll: "collection2",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            nim: 1234
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "from": {
        "$addToSet": "$$ROOT.from"
      },
      "doc": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      from: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$doc"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: "$doc._id",
      docName: "$doc.docName"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d7bHxCd6dPn)

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you very much :D

Comment: Great, you can vote up and accept my answer.

Comment: one more question, please.
how to handle if collection1 data is not found but collection2 data exists?
using the above method can't if the condition is collection1 the data is not found.

Comment: You mean if collection1 do not have 1234, then the result is empty ?

Comment: I update my answer, if it doesn't fit what you need, then give some test data and expected result.

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you very much :D